# How to scroll one line in a ul but keep the width

Tags: html, css, scroll

First: Sorry that the html and css code is in German, but I'm from Germany^^"
So I created a table with some equation in it. I want the equation to be in only one line on mobile setting, so that it is readable well. But when I do this with white-space:nowrap it makes the whole table flow over the screen. Do you have any help how to make only that one line scrollable.

```css
/* Body */
body    {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-image: url(../Bilder/Linien.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 background-color: #D7D7D7;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Mobile Settings */

@media (max-width: 800px) {

 body {
  background-image: none;
  }

 body .Gleichung {
  line-height: 1.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
}

.UebersichtGWrapper {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}

/* Table */

.UebersichtG {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 45%;
 margin: 2%;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 border: 1px black solid;
}

.BoxG {
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}

.BoxTitel {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
 background-color: #D7D7D7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.UebersichtG li {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.UebersichtG li::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}

.Fett {
 font-weight: 600;
}

.Gleichung {
 text-align: left;
 line-height: 0.1;
 border-top: 1px solid;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="UebersichtGWrapper">
                 <div class="UebersichtG">
         <ul class="BoxG">
          <li class="BoxTitel">Dualzahlen bzw. Binärzahlen (Basis = 2)</li>
          <li>b=2, also gibt es nur die beiden Ziffern 0 und 1</li>
          <li>
         <ul class="Gleichung">
          <li class="Fett">1101,101</li>
          <li>= 1&sdot;2<sup>3</sup> + 0&sdot;2<sup>2</sup> + 1&sdot;2<sup>0</sup> + 1&sdot;2<sup>-1</sup> + 0&sdot;2<sup>-2</sup> + 1&sdot;2<sup>-3</sup></li>
          <li>= 1&sdot;8 + 1&sdot;4 + 0&sdot;2 + 1&sdot;1 + 1&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> + 0&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> + 1&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>8</sub></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
          <li>Da die Positionen von Zweierpotenzen gebildet werden, heißen sie Zweier, Vierer, Achter bzw. Halbe, Viertel usw. Die Zugehörigkeit zu den Dualzahlen kennzeichnet man oft mit einem Index: 1101,1012<sub>2</sub></li>
       </ul>
        </div>
                 <div class="UebersichtG">
         <ul class="BoxG">
          <li class="BoxTitel">Hexadezimalzahlen (Basis = 16)</li>
          <li>b=16, hier gibt es 16 Ziffern. Da wir nur 10 Ziffern kennen und jede Ziffer nur aus einem Symbol bestehen darf, setzt man nach der Ziffer 9 mit Buchstaben fort. Ziffern: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F</li>
        <li>
         <ul class="Gleichung">
          <li class="Fett">F2C7,B2</li>
          <li>= F&sdot;16<sup>3</sup> + 2&sdot;16<sup>2</sup> + C&sdot;16<sup>1</sup> + 7&sdot;16<sup>0</sup> + B&sdot;16<sup>-1</sup> + 2&sdot;16<sup>-2</sup></li>
          <li>= F&sdot;4096 + 2&sdot;256 + C&sdot;16 + 7&sdot;1 + B&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>16</sub> + 2&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>256</sub></li>
          <li>= 15&sdot;4096 + 2&sdot;256 + 12&sdot;16 + 7&sdot;1 + 11&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>16</sub> + 2&sdot;<sup>1</sup>/<sub>256</sub></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Da die Positionen hier von 16er-Potenzen gebildet werden, heißen sie hier Einer, Sechzehner, Zweihundertsechsundfünfziger bzw. Sechzehntel, Zweihundersechsundfünfzigstel usw. Die Zugehörigkeit zu den Hexadezimalzahlen kennzeichnet man oft mit einem Index: F2C7,B216<sub>16</sub></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help a bit, normally you can add overflow in x direction with "overflow-x: scroll;", but I'm not sure if this is working fine here.
But the order of the code is important here, so use it like this and it should be a bit better. (Also in Responsiv ist es jetzt schon besser, aber um das perfekt zu machen, dauert das noch ein bisschen länger...)

```
    body    {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-image: url(../Bilder/Linien.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-color: #D7D7D7;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .UebersichtGWrapper {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* Table */

    .UebersichtG    {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 45%;
        margin: 2%;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        border: 1px black solid;
    }

    .BoxG   {
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .BoxTitel   {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background-color: #D7D7D7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }

    .UebersichtG li {
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: -40px;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .UebersichtG li::-webkit-scrollbar  {
        display: none;
    }

    .Fett   {
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .Gleichung  {
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 0.1;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }   

    /* Mobile Settings */

    @media only screen and (max-width:800px){

        body    {
            background-image: none;
      }

        body .Gleichung {
            line-height: 1.5;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }


    .UebersichtGWrapper {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .UebersichtG    {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 2%;
        padding: 0;
        float: none;
        border: 1px black solid;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I now found the problem. The "UebersichtGWrapper" was still being displayed as a table. Now that I changed this to display: block; it's fixed.